# Policy assertion was evaluated as "UNKNOWN". [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector] selectAlternatives

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

> Policy assertion
>   "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts"
>   was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
>   [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector] 
>   selectAlternatives

I am getting this warning,while attempting to hit a web service,what could be the best solution to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?